# Content Type Hub, Inherited content types and retention policies don't play well together

Tags: content-type-hub

In SharePoint 2013, I'm using a hierarchy of content types, and the content type hub, and retention policies and they don't appear to play well together.  I'm wondering if anyone has a work-around...

The details:

On the Hub site collection:
I have Base Content type, on which I have a retention policy.
I have a Derived Content Type, which inherits the retention policy.
When the Expiration Policy timer job runs, documents of both the Base and the Derived content types are properly deleted.

On the Subscribing site collection:
I have documents using both the Base and Derived content types.
When the Expiration Policy timer job runs, documents of the Base content type are properly deleted, but documents of the Derived content type are not.

This seems like a bug - can anyone convince me otherwise?

And more immediately, how can I work around it?

My first attempt was to define a retention policy on both Base *and* Derived content types, but SharePoint doesn't want derived content types to have different policies from their parents, so I'm prevented from that.  And SharePoint won't let me apply retention policies on the subscribing site collection (because of course, it's properly inheriting it from the publishing hub.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have a content type hierarchy and the retention policy is not taking affect. Do you resolve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a great answer - when I went back to retest it again a week or two later, it worked properly.  i don't know if I was making a mistake in my first test (quite possible), or whether some other changes I made fixed it (i was changing other aspects of the content type definitions)(, or a Cumulative Update corrected it.

Comment: I've found that even though they inherit, I need to republish all derived content types. Are changes to your policy being published? I've found that this is not occurring and there's no way to publish them directly.